# Cognos integration with asp.net web page

Tags: asp.net, cognos, cognos-bi

I wanted to integrate cognos and fetch the reports in pdf/chart format from cognos server. I have not worked much on cognos framework.

I have checked other question  also for the same but not got any proper answer to this question.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of APIs for orchestrating activities or retrieving data in Cognos.

Based on the specific use case you're citing, I'd lean towards the URL interface (item #1 below).

1. Cognos exposes a "URL" interface for some of the most common activities. This includes running a report, viewing saved report output, opening a report in report studio, etc.  In later versions of Cognos,they added the "cognosLaunch" JavaScript that you can include from the gateway.  This allows you to use Cognos JS functions to effectively build up these URLs. If you want documentation on this, search the Cognos SDK Guide for "cognosLaunch".
2. You can use the Cognos SDK. This is the most powerful way to orchestrate things in Cognos. It has a large surface area and a fairly steep learning curve, but if you're willing to invest the time in it, the possibilities are endless
3. You can use the Cognos Mashup service - this is kind of like "SDK Lite". Mashup is easier to use (vs. the SDK) but exposes a much smaller surface area. As the name implies, its useful for mashup type scenarios.

Here's an article which describes Cognos Mashup vs. Cognos SDK, and provides some heuristics for when you would choose one over the other :

http://www.motio.com/blog/2010/11/01/cognos-sdk-vs-cognos-mashup.do